# Foreign Resident in Iraq applying for a Swiss Visa. How long will I have to stay in Turkey before I get my passport back to travel?

Tags: visas, schengen, international-travel

I am a foreign national working and living in Iraq and I have to fly to Istanbul to apply for a Swiss visa. I would like to know how long will it take to get my passport back with or without the visa so I have an idea for hotel booking, etc..

Answer (score 3):

According to [TLSContact](https://ch.tlscontact.com/tr/IST/page.php?pid=help#when_apply) (the company handling Swiss visas in Turkey):

> **The average application process time is 6 to 8 working days**, but it
>   can take much longer under certain circumstances (e.g. missing
>   documents, work visa, etc.). The Consulate General advises you to
>   submit your application at least 15 calendar days before the scheduled
>   departure.

So presuming you want to be on the safe side, I'd plan at least **10 days** in Istanbul. Note that you can also have someone else pick up your passport or have the consulate send your documents by UPS, although I'm not sure how reliable UPS is for deliveries to Iraq.

Comment: Thank you for replying. Seems then I can't leave and apply in a weekend.  I have only two weeks vacay and would like to do everything, getting the visa and visiting Switzerland, in that time. Or if I don't get the  visa, I'd go back to Iraq.

Comment: @KahaAsim you can always change your plans and visit a different Schengen country that has a consulate in Iraq.

Comment: That could also be done. But my friends have been asking that I visit for about 2 years now. I have used up all my "I can'ts" and they came to see me in Iraq.